# Amazon MWS Performance of XML vs Flat File Upload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Is there a significant performance difference between using the MWS XML API vs using MWS to upload flat files for adding items to FBA inventory?

My client wants to be able to immediately print an FNSKU after the item has been through our listing procedure. The listing procedure gathers all of the data on the item that Amazon needs to create the record in inventory.

Currently, there is another processing step that uploads a flat file with all of the item information, but takes ~10 minutes to process. He's currently using a software product called Listtee to process FBA inventory, and it is capable of immediately returning the FNSKU somehow. I'm wondering if it may be because they use the XML process instead of the file upload process.

Has anyone else had any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one major difference between CSV (=flat files) and XML uploads that may impact performance: The XML format requires multiple feeds (general listing, images, pricing etc.) to list a single item while the CSV format doesn't. Please note that in my experience it is not necessary to wait for the first feed to be processed before sending the others, because I've only seen them being processed in order and one at a time, but others on Stack Overflow [disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202207/sequence-constraints-of-product-feeds-for-amazon-mws).

But even for short feeds (one single item CSV, three single item XMLs) neither method is anywhere near instant - in my experience they're both more in the order of a couple of minutes until processed depending on Amazon's current server load.

So I wondered how ListTee might do it, and found this on their [FAQ page](https://listtee.zendesk.com/entries/20883318-F-A-Qs): They require an AWS registration and Seller Central credentials, but are *not* asking for MWS information *at all*. So I'm guessing they use a scraper of sorts to give immediate feedback. (The AWS registration is probably needed for the additional "pull in prices for both FBA and Non-FBA" function described on their [How ListTee Works](http://www.listtee.com/why-use-listtee/how-listtee-works/) page)

Please note that while Amazon most probably has no problem with anybody doing this, it might technically be in violation of their [terms of service](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=508088) as it might count as "any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools" (see "License and Access").

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was thinking that was how they were doing it, or creating items in advance and then updating the item information somehow when you send your item information in so that the FNSKU is already generated, but couldn't get that to work.